# Modify LatinIME Android 2.3

Tags: android, android-source

I'm porting Android on my device, but have a problem with keyboard. It's small. I change height and weight of keys. But I stell need to change margin between keys. How can I do that? Thx!

Comment: Can you show us how you changed the height and weight of keys?

Comment: @JermaineXu all you need is file in xml res "kbd_qwerty.xml".